# Select a specific cell in Pandas dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I know that it is basic but I can't find it, how can I select a specific cell in a dataframe
(ex. by the person's name)

```
exam_data  = {'name': ['Anastasia', 'Dima', 'Katherine', 'James', 'Emily', 'Michael', 'Matthew', 'Laura', 'Kevin', 'Jonas'],
        'score': [12.5, 9, 16.5, np.nan, 9, 20, 14.5, np.nan, 8, 19],
        'attempts': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
        'qualify': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'],
        'state' : ['calf', 'ny', 'ver', 'colo', 'wshg', 'calf', 'calf', 'ny', 'calf', 'ny']}
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
df=pd.DataFrame(exam_data,index=labels)
df.at[df['name']=='Emily','score']=10 # This will raise an error "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError"
```

This is important if the frame is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) with [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), you should use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead :

```
df.loc[df['name']=='Emily', 'score'] = 10
```

Output :

```
print(df)

        name  score  attempts qualify state
a  Anastasia   12.5         1     yes  calf
b       Dima    9.0         3      no    ny
c  Katherine   16.5         2     yes   ver
d      James    NaN         3      no  colo
e      Emily   10.0         2      no  wshg
f    Michael   20.0         3     yes  calf
g    Matthew   14.5         1     yes  calf
h      Laura    NaN         1      no    ny
i      Kevin    8.0         2      no  calf
j      Jonas   19.0         1     yes    ny
```